# indexing two dimentational array

Tags: python

I have an array: `array[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]`.
I'm seeking a way to extract every other row and every other column, e.g. `array[[1,3],[9,11]]`. What is the best way to do this in python?

Comment: what do you mean by `every other row and every other column"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy`

```
In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])

In [9]: a[::2,::2]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this.

```
>>> [x[::2] for x in [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]][::2]]
[[1, 3], [9, 11]]
```

The `[::2]` syntax means "every second element of the array".